# Swing problem!(problem in showing a frame)

Tags: java, swing, networking

sorry for posting a lot of code!!I don't know that why my ListFrame doesn't work???
these are the classes.At first I run the MainServer and then I will run the MainFrame in the other package.and then by inserting a correct user name and password ,the Listframe will be shown,BUT I click on menu bar or list or delete button but nothing will happen.why?? please help me.

MainSerevr class :

```
public class MainServer {

static Socket client = null;
static ServerSocket server = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Server is starting...");
    System.out.println("Server is listening...");

    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(5050);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port 5050");
        System.exit(-1);

    }
    try {
        client = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Client Connected...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Accept failed: 5050");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader streamIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

        boolean done = false;
        String line;
        while (!done) {
            line = streamIn.readLine();
            if (line.equalsIgnoreCase(".bye")) {
                done = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Client says: " + line);
            }
        }

        streamIn.close();
        client.close();
        server.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Error in streams " + e);
    }
}}
```

ListFrame:

```
 public class ListFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame implements PersonsModelChangeListener {

    private InformationClass client;
    private static DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    private ListSelectionModel moDel;

    /** Creates new form ListFrame */
    public ListFrame(InformationClass client) {
        initComponents();
        this.client = client;
        jList1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);


        fillTable();
        Manager.addListener(this);
    }

    private void deleteAPerson() {
        int index = jList1.getSelectedIndex();
        String yahooId = (String) jList1.getSelectedValue();
        model.remove(index);
        Manager.removeApersonFromSQL(yahooId);
        int size = model.getSize();
        if (size == 0) {
            jButton1.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            if (index == size) {
                index--;
            }
            jList1.setSelectedIndex(index);
            jList1.ensureIndexIsVisible(index);

        }
    }                       



  private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        AddAPerson frame = new AddAPerson(client);
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }                                          

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        deleteAPerson();
    }                                        

    private void jList1ValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                    
        MainClient.setText("");
        MainClient.runAClient();
        ChatFrame frame = new ChatFrame(client);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }  
    public void fillTable() {
    try {
        List<InformationClass> list = null;
        list = Manager.getClientListFromMySQL();
        if (list == null) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You should add a person to your list", "Information", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
            return;
        } else {


            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                InformationClass list1 = list.get(i);
                model.add(i, list1.getId());
            }

            jList1.setModel(model);
        }


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ListFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

MainClient class:

```
public class MainClient {


private static InformationClass info = new InformationClass();
private static Socket c;
private static String text;

public static String getText() {
    return text;
}

public static void setText(String text) {
    MainClient.text = text;
}

private static PrintWriter os;
private static BufferedReader is;
static boolean closed = false;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void runAClient() {
    try {
        c = new Socket("localhost", 5050);

        os = new PrintWriter(c.getOutputStream());
        is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));

        String teXt = getText();
        os.println(teXt);
        if(c!=null&& is!=null&&os!=null){
        String line = is.readLine();
        System.out.println("Text received: " + line);
        }


        c.close();
        is.close();
        os.close();


    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);

    }

}


}
```

EDIT:I have found the problem,which is because of writting MainClient.runAClient() in code ,where should I put it? please help me.

Comment: This code does not even compile. Please rework the example code you’re posting to the smallest possible but still compilable example that exhibits the behaviour you are having problems with. Also, check http://sscce.org/ for further advice on how to post correct code examples.

Comment: I have found the problem,which is because of adding the MainClient.runAClient() in this code.where should I put it?

Answer (score 1):

This [article](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.help/msg/9f7f86db103f35c9) contains an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that illustrates a simple client-server GUI. You may find it instructive. If so, consider how you would address the bug found in the last line of the `Echo(Kind kind)` constructor.

Comment: I have found the problem which is because of writing the MainClient.runAClient() method in the code.whould you please help me that where should i put this line?thanks

Comment: I have no way to test your code. In general, you can start your client thread any time after the server is ready to accept new connections. In the `main()` method of the example I cited, the server starts first, followed by the client; both run until either is closed.